# Compare AM and GM

Tags: co.combinatorics, real-analysis, inequalities

\begin{gather*}
M_g=(x_1\times x_2\times\dotsb\times x_n)^{1/n} \\
M_a=\frac1 n\times (x_1+x_2+\dotsb+x_n).
\end{gather*}

Is it true that $$\lvert M_g-M_a\rvert \leq (\max(x_i) /\min(x_i)) \times(\max(x_i) - \min(x_i))?\label{1}\tag{1}$$

And is it true that

$$\lvert M_g-M_a\rvert\leq (\max(x_i) /\min(x_i)) \times\left( \frac1{n^2}\sum \limits _{(i, j) \in \{1,\dotsc,n\}^2} \lvert x_i-x_j\rvert\right)?\label{2}\tag{2}$$

Ps.: $x_i\in\mathbb R_+^*$.

Comment: there is even a stronger inequality, you can remove the factor $\max(x_i) /\min(x_i)$ from the right-hand-side.

Comment: Both AM and GM are between $\min_ix_i$ and $\max_ix_i$, hence their difference is obviously bounded by $\max_ix_i-\min_ix_i$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Now?

Comment: please don't change the question without leaving a record of the original question; you want to avoid presenting us with a moving target.

Comment: There are many inequalities providing lower or upper bounds on $M_g-M_a$, have you consulted the literature to see if it contains your inequalities? See e.g. Chapter 2 of "Handbook of Means and Their Inequalities" by P.S. Bullen.

Comment: I did not find this inequality anywhere. Can you give a reference where we actually find this inequality or one that allows us to deduce this one?

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/q/122411/

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev The inequality (2) is not there.

Comment: @Dattier: It's not per se, but there are stronger ones.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Almost-converses to the AM-GM inequality](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122411/almost-converses-to-the-am-gm-inequality)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inequality $(2)$ (even with factor $\frac12$ in the r.h.s.) follows from the inequality quoted in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/215094):
$$M_a - M_g \leq \frac1{2n\min_k x_k} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - M_a)^2.$$
First, we notice that
\begin{split}
(x_i - M_a)^2 &\leq \max_k x_k\cdot |x_i-M_a|\\
&= \max_k x_k\cdot \left|\frac1n \sum_{j=1}^n (x_i - x_j)\right| \\
& \leq \frac{\max_k x_k}n \sum_{j=1}^n |x_i - x_j|.
\end{split}
Then
$$\frac1{2n\min_k x_k} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - M_a)^2 \leq \frac12 \frac{\max_k x_k}{\min_k x_k} \frac1{n^2} \sum_{i,j=1}^n |x_i - x_j|.$$
QED